# Loop over image for live stream transcoding in VLC

Tags: video-streaming, vlc

I'm using VLC to transcode a snapshot from an IP Cam into a video stream that can be received by a browser.

This works great in the desktop client as VLC just leaves the image on the screen until the next arrives:

```
vlc -I image "http://example.com/cameras/1/image" --image-duration 1
--image-fps 1 --image-realtime --loop -R
```

How can I now transcode what I see on the screen into HLS? For example, I am using this with some success on RTSP feeds:

```
--sout='#transcode{fps=25,vcodec=h264,venc=x264{profile=baseline,level=30,keyint=30,ref=1}}:std{access=livehttp{seglen=10,delsegs=false,numsegs=10,index=/tmp/video/test/live.m3u8,index-url=fileSequence######.ts},mux=ts{use-key-frames},dst=/tmp/video/test/fileSequence######.ts}'
```

I believe the way to do this in the past was to use the ['fake'](http://boxysean.com/blog/2012/07/03/stream-a-slideshow-of-images-with-vlc-11x/) module but that was deprecated in 0.9.0. I'm running VLC 2.2.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Any insight you can provide will be helpful!